# Display PDF in Web Application

Tags: asp.net, pdf, web

I have googled this, searched this, looked through SO and other sites (I've been trying to read on this issue for hours now), but I still can't seem to find a satisfactory solution to what seems to be a simple, common programming issue.

Let me set the scene:

- I've got a website/web application that allows the user to search a SQL Server library.
- Most of the documents related to the search results are PDF files.
- The PDF files are stored inside of the SQL Server database a BLOBs.
- I want to be able to dynamically pull a PDF from the database and display it to the user.
- In order to preserve the user's search progress, I think I'd like to open the file in another browser window/tab
- I've figured out how to save the PDF to the server in a specified directory.
- I **DON'T** want the user to see the path to the file.
- Within reason, I want a solution that works in all major browsers:
  1. Internet Explorer
  2. FireFox
  3. Chrome
  4. Safari (including iPhone/iPad Mobile Safari)
- I'd prefer not to buy a 3rd party component, but I'm willing to go that route if necessary.
- I don't think I want to send the file as a download (which I think I've figured out how to do), because wouldn't this fail on iPhone/iPad?

Every solution I've tried so far has some basic problems wrong with it:

- Using iFrames seems to fail miserably on iPhones/iPad
- Using Server.Transfer (I'm using ASP.NET) shows gibberish instead of PDF
- I've tried a couple of demo 3rd party solutions, but they stink, too!

I can't figure it out! I'm really a desktop developer, and this was ***EASY*** in Windows! Why is it so hard with the web?

Am I stupid and this is really an easy exercise, or is this basic task really that hard?

Please help point me in the right direction!

Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't know ASP.NET, but I think the reason you got gibberish when you used Server.Transfer could be that you didn't set the content type header of the response to `application/pdf` - or did you? :)

Comment: I understand what you're saying (from a conceptual standpoint), but it doesn't make sense to me (from a functional standpoint). What's the difference between clicking on an <a> tag that points to a PDF and doing a Server.Transfer('/file.pdf')? The first one seems to work, but the second doesn't. If I tell the browser to load a PDF file, shouldn't it figure out the MIME type from the file extension? Also, when/how do I set the content type header when executing a Server.Transfer? (You might not know that if you're not an ASP.NET developer.)

Comment: Ah, you're doing a Server.Transfer to a .PDF file? I thought you were transferring to another ASP.NET script which displays the PDF inline, like the answer by Rich Andrews below outlines. In that case, you need to set the content type within the script, as you can see in his answer :)

Comment: Yeah, as you can see, DotNetUser's answer got me working (and was similar to Rich Andrews' answer). I'm still unclear, though, why the gibberish is displaying. Why doesn't the browser know to show a PDF when I call the Server.Transfer? Anyway, thanks for answering.

Comment: I suspect it's because server.transfer just replaces what is returned from the current url (it stays the same as far the browser is concerned) but if you were to response.redirect instead then the browser will interpret it as a new request and process it accordingly. http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3299641/ServerTransfer-Vs-ResponseRedirect.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This link might be useful to you,

http://nilangshah.wordpress.com/2007/05/28/successfully-stream-a-pdf-to-browser-through-https/

You can have pdf opened in a new tab by speccifying target="_blank" for the link. ByteArray mentioned in the blog is your BLOB from the DB. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried adding a http header with content-disposition-inline? Also you may want to write the result directly to the output response instead of saving it. This would ensure the files actual path is not displayed as your writing it to the response directly.

Eg

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition","inline");
Response.BinaryWrite(myfilestream.ToArray());
```

Where myfilestream is a memory stream or if you already have a byte array from your blob you can write it directly to the response without the toarray

Comment: This answer is close to the accepted answer, so I up voted it. Thanks!

Comment: this seems to work on IE but on FF, it ask to open it on default viewer or save it (meaning to download) but on chrome it literary display on the same window.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net has a `ReportViewer` server control that can be used to display PDF files.

Much of the documentation about this feature is about how to generate a report and export it to PDF. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254293.aspx) really isn't very helpful. I suppose everyone is relying on Adobe Reader and not looking for an alternative?

But it is possible also to **import and display a PDF**. This code seemed to work for [this user](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/713648e4-3a35-4ea8-bd0c-826d919b1be9/):

```
public static void RenderToPdf(ReportViewer reportViewer, Boolean forceDownload)
{
    string path = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath)) ? reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath : reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath;
    RenderToPdf(reportViewer, forceDownload, System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path));
}

public static void RenderToPdf(ReportViewer reportViewer, Boolean forceDownload, string fileNameWithoutExtension)
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

    if (!context.Response.Buffer)
    {
        return; //can not clear the buffer, so exit
    }

    //define out properties
    Warning[] warnings;
    string mimeType, encoding, fileNameExtension;
    string[] streams;

    //get pdf content
    Byte[] pdfContent = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);

    //cancel and clear the existing output!
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    //add a header so that the user can save the target as a downloaded file
    if (forceDownload)
    {
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.pdf", fileNameWithoutExtension));
    }

    context.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfContent);
    context.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: I was unable to get this to work. The `Byte[] pdfContent = reportViewer...` line kept giving me an unhandled exception. So I bailed on this method and went to the accepted solution.

Comment: Too bad. I suppose there's a reason why there is so little documentation...I'll leave this here as a caution to folks tempted to spend a lot of effort trying to get the ASP.Net approach to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do to open a PDF document in the browser from an ASP.NET (aspx) page.
In the page OnLoad:

```
        this.Response.Clear();
        this.Response.Buffer = true;
        this.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        this.Response.AddHeader("content-length", pdfReportStream.Length.ToString());
        this.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfReportStream.ToByteArray());

        this.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for client side pdf client, you can have a look at [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) that can display any PDF with the default viewer included (you'll have to transform the viewer.html into a view if in MVC but it's quite easy).
It's open source and alive.I had to adapt it a little to be able to show pdf annotations on iphone (digital signatures) by commenting some lines in the js.