# Displaying PDF file on browser Issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, pdf, iframe

I need help regarding on displaying pdf in a browser. This is my real and simple agenda why I need to do this.

- Click a certain button in the page, to be precise, a imagebutton in
  an ajax modal popup.
- New window will display, and pdf will be    rendered on the window.

Below are my attempt to solve the problem.

- **Using window.open**

  - using this javascript function is a tricky one but still i manage to overcome some but stranded on a certain difficulty, this does not work on IE9 64bit (in IE 32bit it works). Pdf did not display and always ask to download the file instead. In other browser pdf display as expected on the popup window. Other issue for this is that, this window will block to display if popup blocker is on in the browser and can resolve unless you disable it, but my client didn't want to go all the trouble just to disable or enable it and not all the users are computer literate to understand this case.
- **Using Process.Start**

  - using this method seems to shed some light to my troubles but did not last for long. I decided to when the button was click it will display the pdf using the default pdf viewer software in the machine (Acrobat Reader). In development, this method seems to work but when I deploy the site, Process.Start seems not working due to some security issue on the server and I don't want to configure the server as I have limited access on it. Other thing here is that when pdf viewer software is not installed on the machine another issue will arise. I have some solution on this but knowing the fact that Process.Start is not not working on server I drop to test this solution.
- **Using iframe**

  - ok so window.open does not work so i will create a popup to make it compatible in all browser. I need modalpop from ajax for this to be the placeholder of the iframe. the pdf that i want to display is generated at the first place so the only thing i need to do is to point the src attribute of the iframe to the location of the generated pdf in the server. this seems to work in all browser and popup modal display as what i wanted but still problem arises on IE browser. Pdf doesn't seems to display in iframe instead asking for download is what i get.

on the list of method that I tried do you guys have some solution that will solve my problem. I really need help, and I will appreciate any help from you guys. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at Rich Andrews answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647551/display-pdf-in-web-application